# In Azure Devops Variable Scope Value Release mean

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops what does variable scope value **Release** mean? In the same drop down there are other stages that mean it only applies for that stage. Does **Release** mean it applies to all stages?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, when a variable scope is set to `Release` it allows the value to be used across all stages and tasks in the release pipeline. If scope is set to a specific stage, then it is available in that stage only.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#custom-variables

Answer (score 11):

> Does Release mean it applies to all stages?

Yes. While you set the scope as **Release**, it will cover all of the scopes during this release, including all of the stages.

[image]

You can see this from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#custom-variables).

And also, if you have a variable with the same name in multiple scopes, it will be used according to the following **precedence**:

[image]

1 means the highest precedence.

This has been explained in detail in [Expansion of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#expansion-of-variables), you can refer to it for more details.

Comment: Thanks for including precedence. But what's the precedence of two variables in the pipeline, one with a Release scope and the other with a Stage scope? I assume Stage wins but don't see that documented.

Comment: My testing verifies that `Release` scope is overridden by the more specific `Stage` scope when you have two variables with the same name but different scopes.